# web view is not working in android

Tags: java, android

I trying to create a new browser for android using eclipse. I had added webview, edit text and button to my browser app...

and in MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
ImageButton btngo;
    EditText eturl;
    WebView wvbrowser;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 btngo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        eturl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        wvbrowser = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webView1);

        btngo.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
wvbrowser.loadUrl(eturl.getText().toString());
}
```

What should do to get correct output...???? ANy help...???

Comment: but what is your problem?

Comment: what are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

1.when you are clicking on imageview btngo it's not getting the url from edittext eturl , please check its value ,May be it may help to you
2. please check internet connection
3.Also check Internet permission properly added in manifest file